# NLTK: Find contexts of size 2k for a word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, collocation

I have a corpus and I have a word. For each occurrence of the word in the corpus I want to get a list containing the k words before and the k words after the word. I am doing this algorithmically OK (see below) but I wondered whether NLTK is providing some functionality for my needs that I missed?

```
def sized_context(word_index, window_radius, corpus):
    """ Returns a list containing the window_size amount of words to the left
    and to the right of word_index, not including the word at word_index.
    """

    max_length = len(corpus)

    left_border = word_index - window_radius
    left_border = 0 if word_index - window_radius < 0 else left_border

    right_border = word_index + 1 + window_radius
    right_border = max_length if right_border > max_length else right_border

    return corpus[left_border:word_index] + corpus[word_index+1: right_border]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest, nltk-ish way to do this is with `nltk.ngrams()`.

```
words = nltk.corpus.brown.words()
k = 5
for ngram in nltk.ngrams(words, 2*k+1, pad_left=True, pad_right=True, pad_symbol=" "):
    if ngram[k+1].lower() == "settle":
        print(" ".join(ngram))
```

`pad_left` and `pad_right` ensure that all words get looked at. This is important if you don't let your concordances span across sentences (hence: lots of boundary cases).

If you want to ignore punctuation in the window size, you can strip it before scanning:

```
words = (w for w in nltk.corpus.brown.words() if re.search(r"\w", w))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use the nltk's functionality, you can use nltk's `ConcordanceIndex`. In order to base the width of the display on the number of words instead of the number of characters (the latter being the default for `ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance`), you can merely create a subclass of `ConcordanceIndex` with something like this:

```
from nltk import ConcordanceIndex

class ConcordanceIndex2(ConcordanceIndex):
    def create_concordance(self, word, token_width=13):
        "Returns a list of contexts for @word with a context <= @token_width"
        half_width = token_width // 2
        contexts = []
        for i, token in enumerate(self._tokens):
            if token == word:
                start = i - half_width if i >= half_width else 0
                context = self._tokens[start:i + half_width + 1]
                contexts.append(context)
        return contexts
```

Then you can obtain your results like this:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
>>> my_corpus = 'The gerenuk fled frantically across the vast valley, whereas the giraffe merely turned indignantly and clumsily loped away from the valley into the nearby ravine.'  # my corpus
>>> tokens = wordpunct_tokenize(my_corpus)
>>> c = ConcordanceIndex2(tokens)
>>> c.create_concordance('valley')  # returns a list of lists, since words may occur more than once in a corpus
[['gerenuk', 'fled', 'frantically', 'across', 'the', 'vast', 'valley', ',', 'whereas', 'the', 'giraffe', 'merely', 'turned'], ['and', 'clumsily', 'loped', 'away', 'from', 'the', 'valley', 'into', 'the', 'nearby', 'ravine', '.']]
```

The `create_concordance` method I created above is based upon the nltk's `ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance` method, which works like this:

```
>>> c = ConcordanceIndex(tokens)
>>> c.print_concordance('valley')
Displaying 2 of 2 matches:
                                  valley , whereas the giraffe merely turn
 and clumsily loped away from the valley into the nearby ravine .
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks more NLTK-esk, but still the logic is handcrafted. I was hoping for something implemented, tested and most important: optimized within the scope of the framework.